# select and use appropriate decoder as decoder for new item while preserving error accumulation

Tags: scala, decoder, circe

If I have some point where my logic needs to diverge and thus have need to select 1 of some set of possible decoders to use, this issue can arise.

Consider this code snippet:

```scala
import cats.implicits.{catsSyntaxTuple3Semigroupal, catsSyntaxTuple2Semigroupal}
import io.circe.{Decoder, HCursor}

sealed trait Example

object Example {
  case class OptionOne(
    name: String,
    time: String,
    platform: String
  ) extends Example

  object OptionOne {
    implicit val decoder: Decoder[OptionOne] = {
      (
        Decoder[String].prepare(_.downField("event")),
        Decoder[String].prepare(_.downField("time")),
        Decoder[String].prepare(_.downField("platform"))
        )
        .mapN(OptionOne(_, _, _))
    }
  }

  case class OptionTwo(
    name: String,
    time: String
  ) extends Example

  object OptionTwo {
    implicit val decoder: Decoder[OptionTwo] = {
      (
        Decoder[String].prepare(_.downField("event")),
        Decoder[String].prepare(_.downField("time"))
        )
        .mapN(OptionTwo(_, _))
    }
  }

  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Example] = (a: HCursor) => {
    a.get[String]("event").flatMap {
      case "some_precise_name" => OptionTwo.decoder(a)
      case _ => OptionOne.decoder(a)
    }
  }
}
```

If conditionally based on the value of the `event` value I want to have either `OptionOne` or `OptionTwo` selected, the decoder for `Example` does successfully do this. Additionally, it does return the decoding failure if there is a problem. However, if you want the errors to accumulate, this is where the problem emerges.

If you consider this JSON object for testing:

```
Json.obj(
  ("event", "randomEvent".asJson),
  ("time", 8.asJson),
  ("platform", 5.asJson)
  )
```

and pass this in as such: `Example.decoder.decodeAccumulating(inJsonInvalid.hcursor)`, only the first error is returned rather than both errors expected.

So the question is this: how can this be done in a way that preserves the accumulation of errors?

[EDIT] to help with clarification, here is a test suite I would expect to pass for the solution to work:

```scala
class ExampleSuite
  extends AnyFunSuite
    with Matchers
    with Inside {
  test("Decoder -- OptionOne") {
    val inJsonValidApp: Json =
      Json.obj(
        ("event", "something".asJson),
        ("time", "2021-05-05 20:09:57.448".asJson),
        ("platform", "app".asJson),
        ("context", Json.obj(
          ("app_version", "5.7.9".asJson)
          ))
        )
    noException should be thrownBy OptionOne.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonValidApp)
    inside(OptionOne.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonValidApp)) {
      case Right(OptionOne(name, time, platform)) =>
        name should be("something")
        time should be("2021-05-05 20:09:57.448")
        platform should be("app")
    }

    val inJsonInvalid =
      Json.obj(
        ("event", "randomEvent".asJson),
        ("time", 8.asJson),
        ("platform", 5.asJson)
        )
    noException should be thrownBy OptionOne.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonInvalid)
    inside(OptionOne.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonInvalid)) {
      case Left(DecodingFailure(msg, ops)) =>
        msg should be("String")
        ops should be(List(DownField("time")))
    }

    noException should be thrownBy OptionOne.decoder.decodeAccumulating(inJsonInvalid.hcursor)
    inside(OptionOne.decoder.decodeAccumulating(inJsonInvalid.hcursor)) {
      case Invalid(NonEmptyList(head, tail)) =>
        inside(head) {
          case DecodingFailure(msg, ops) =>
            msg should be("String")
            ops should be(List(DownField("time")))
        }
        inside(tail) {
          case List(DecodingFailure(msg, ops)) =>
            msg should be("String")
            ops should be(List(DownField("platform")))
        }
    }
  }
  test("Decoder -- OptionTwo") {
    val inJsonValidApp: Json =
      Json.obj(
        ("event", "something".asJson),
        ("time", "2021-05-05 20:09:57.448".asJson),
        ("platform", "app".asJson)
        )
    noException should be thrownBy OptionTwo.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonValidApp)
    inside(OptionTwo.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonValidApp)) {
      case Right(OptionTwo(name, time)) =>
        name should be("something")
        time should be("2021-05-05 20:09:57.448")
    }

    val inJsonInvalid =
      Json.obj(
        ("event", "randomEvent".asJson),
        ("platform", "bee".asJson)
        )
    noException should be thrownBy OptionTwo.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonInvalid)
    inside(OptionTwo.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonInvalid)) {
      case Left(DecodingFailure(msg, ops)) =>
        msg should be("Attempt to decode value on failed cursor")
        ops should be(List(DownField("time")))
    }
  }

  test("Decoder -- Example (valid)") {
    val inJsonValidApp: Json =
      Json.obj(
        ("event", "something".asJson),
        ("time", "2021-05-05 20:09:57.448".asJson),
        ("platform", "app".asJson)
        )
    noException should be thrownBy Example.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonValidApp)
    inside(Example.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonValidApp)) {
      case Right(OptionOne(name, time, platform)) =>
        name should be("something")
        time should be("2021-05-05 20:09:57.448")
        platform should be("app")
    }

    val inJsonBE: Json =
      Json.obj(
        ("event", "some_precise_name".asJson),
        ("time", "2021-05-05 20:09:57.448".asJson),
        ("platform", "app".asJson)
        )
    noException should be thrownBy Example.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonBE)
    inside(Example.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonBE)) {
      case Right(OptionTwo(name, time)) =>
        name should be("some_precise_name")
        time should be("2021-05-05 20:09:57.448")
    }
  }
  test("Decoder -- Example (invalid, single)") {
    val inJsonInvalid =
      Json.obj(
        ("event", "randomEvent".asJson),
        ("time", 5.asJson),
        ("platform", "bee".asJson)
        )
    noException should be thrownBy Example.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonInvalid)
    inside(Example.decoder.decodeJson(inJsonInvalid)) {
      case Left(DecodingFailure(msg, ops)) =>
        msg should be("String")
        ops should be(List(DownField("time")))
    }
  }

  test("Decoder -- Example (invalid, multiple)") {
    val inJsonInvalid =
      Json.obj(
        ("event", "randomEvent".asJson),
        ("time", 8.asJson),
        ("platform", 5.asJson)
        )
    noException should be thrownBy Example.decoder.decodeAccumulating(inJsonInvalid.hcursor)
    inside(Example.decoder.decodeAccumulating(inJsonInvalid.hcursor)) {
      case Invalid(NonEmptyList(head, tail)) =>
        inside(head) {
          case DecodingFailure(msg, ops) =>
            msg should be("String")
            ops should be(List(DownField("time")))
        }
        inside(tail) {
          case List(DecodingFailure(msg, ops)) =>
            msg should be("String")
            ops should be(List(DownField("platform")))
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since they are Decoders, you can combine them in a such way:

```
implicit val decoder: Decoder[Example] = List[Decoder[Example]](
  Decoder[OptionOne].widen,
  Decoder[OptionTwo].widen,
  ...
).reduceLeft(_ or _)
```

it will just try each one

Comment: I updated the question to include some test code to perhaps help with clarifying -- unfortunately this solution doesn't pass on two accounts -- both for the error accumulation (`Decoder -- Example (invalid, multiple)` test) and that it returns a result selecting `OptionOne` rather than `OptionTwo` for the `Decoder -- Example (valid)`'s `inJsonBE` json case.

Comment: the devil is in the details:
we try to parse using each different decoder
and save the result of the last decoder (Either semantics), but the last decoder gives you only one error,
since it has only one field of a different type,
so - it works :)
but we need to clarify semantic